# quotient remainder theorem proof by induction

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand a passage of the proof by induction of the quotient remainder theorem. Let $a,b$ integers with $b \ne 0$. Then there exist unique $q$ and $r$ such as

$a = bq +r, \qquad 0 \le r \lt |b|$

The proof that the proposition $P(0)$ (when $a = 0$ i.e. base of the induction) is true is straightforward and I omit it. Considering the case $a \ge |b|$. The passage I'm studying in the manual is the following:

> Then $a > a - |b| \ge 0$, and for the inductive hypothesis $P(a-|b|)$
>   is true. Which means there exist two inteergs q',r' such as $a-|b| =  bq'+r'$, $0 \le r' \lt |b|$, from which can be deducted a = |b|+ bq' +
>   r'. According to the sign of b, we'll have $a = b(q'+1) +r'$ for $b>0$
>   and $ a = b(q'- 1) +r'$ for $b<0$ with $0 \le r' \lt |b|$ i.e. P(a) is
>   true.

I don't understand it. Particularly why it has shifted the inductive hypothesis to $P(a-|b|)$ instead of $P(a)$

Comment: Can you say what $P$ is?

Comment: This is a proof by strong induction. You assume the result holds for all nonnegative integers strictly smaller than $a$, and you want to prove it for $a$. But $a-|b|$ is a nonnegative integer that is strictly smaller than $a$, so the induction hypothesis implies that the result holds for $a-|b|$. That is, the inductive hypothesis is "if $0\leq k\lt a$, then $P(k)$." You are trying to prove $P(a)$. You observe that $k=a-|b|$ satisfies $0\leq k\lt a$, and therefore you know that $P(a-|b|)$ holds.

Comment: yes in this case $P_{n+1}$ is equivalent to $P(a)$ and $P_n$ to $P(a−|b|)$. Isn't it?